# How to store formatted date in DataExtension via Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

When I add the following code to a landing page, it stores the Timestamp (which is a date field in the data extension) as 6/13/2014 1:12 PM

Why is it not storing like this instead?  06/13/2014 1:12 PM

SET @status = UpsertData("ENT.ABC", 1, "EMAIL ADDRESS", @e, "TIMESTAMP", FORMAT(SystemDateToLocalDate(NOW()),"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually stored as a SQL datetime; its the intrinsic display formatting giving you issues.  If you really need the format you specified, you can either:

1. Store it as a string.
2. Reformat it when you need to display it using C# format strings.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ok.  this seems to work.  I want to store time in AM/PM.  How do I format this?

Comment: You would use: "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt"